# What is the name of the group $\mathbb Z_2\times \mathbb Z_2\times \mathbb Z_2$?

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups, terminology

I know, that  $\mathbb Z_2\times \mathbb Z_2$ is the Klein four-group. Is there a nice name for  $\mathbb Z_2\times \mathbb Z_2\times \mathbb Z_2$ too?

Comment: No special name for this group, there is name for *such kind of groups*- elementary abelian $2$-groups; you can put more  copies of $Z_2$.

Comment: Elementary, my dear @Watson.

Comment: How about $V_8$?